# Prevent Button Text from Bleeding Out on Browser Resize

Tags: html, css, button, resize

I am trying to prevent button text from overlapping on small window size. I used the <button> tag instead of <input> to allow two lines of text, however when the windows are re-sized, the button text bleeds off the "button" area.

I have tried adjust the button size, changing the "fixed:" property, changing the "inline:" property, to no avail.
Some things I've tried:

- [Button width in css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462251/button-width-in-css3)
- [How to wrap text of html button with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862010/how-to-wrap-text-of-html-button-with-fixed-width)
- [How to wrap text of html button with fixed width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862010/how-to-wrap-text-of-html-button-with-fixed-width)

What button should look like:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/RsP7ch8.png]

What the button does when window is re-sized:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/U5QzabR.png]

**CSS:**

```
.button2 {
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05,
        #0066FF), color-stop(1, #0052CC));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0066FF',
        endColorstr='#0052CC',GradientType=0);
  background-color:#0066FF;
  -moz-border-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px;
  border-radius:6px;
  border:1px solid #6692bd;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:23px;
  font-weight:normal;
  width:100%;
  height: 44px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:-1px 1px 0-1px #488ccf;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="95%" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td text align="center">
      <a href="https://www.example.com">
        <button class="button">Order Now</button>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestions to keep button text within the button area, no matter the size of window?

Comment: Maybe try adding the following CSS: `font-size: some%` along with `text-size: largest`.

Comment: Have you looked at `min-width` or `min-height` and `max-height`?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a `min-width`, and `word-wrap`. You are also establishing the style of `button2` and not `button`

```
.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0066FF), color-stop(1, #0052CC));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0066FF', endColorstr='#0052CC', GradientType=0);
    background-color:#0066FF;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #6692bd;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:-1px 1px 0-1px #488ccf;
    width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 44px;
    word-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/gQ4JD/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Padding instead of height and width
```

```
.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d4eaff;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0066FF), color-stop(1, #0052CC));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #0066FF 5%, #0052CC 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0066FF', endColorstr='#0052CC', GradientType=0);
    background-color:#0066FF;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #6692bd;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:-1px 1px 0-1px #488ccf;
    padding:5px;       
}
```